# Fix jQuery Manual Button Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if(counter > 4){
    counter = 1;
  }
}, 3000);
</script>

 <div class="navigation-manual">
    <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
    <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
    <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
    <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
  </div>
```

so i have a slider an automatic slider , but the button for next image didnt work well for me, i searched for the problem but i still not get it idk why

Comment: this is my first time asking question in here so, if u need to see my full code i can dm u in discord or something

Comment: you doesn't even have the button...

Comment: fixed sorry dumb question

Comment: Where is the button?